# What does "a set of lights" mean?

Tags: grammar

I read this dialog from a certain school's book.
[image]

ECC English Online School

What does a  set of lights mean? Does is mean traffic lights ? If so , why use SET and not just TRAFFIC lights ?

Comment: Because a traffic signal is made up of a set of three lights (red, yellow, green)

Comment: @Jim not only the 'set' of three lights but also the larger 'set' of signals pointing in different directions. A single set of three lights is not usually a lot of use.

Comment: @BoldBen - A very good point.

Answer (score 0):

You can say "until you come to traffic lights" or "until you come to some traffic lights" or even (in Britain at least) "until you you come to some lights". All conversational and all equally valid. Questions such as "why use X and not just Y?" (where X and Y are equally valid ways of saying the same thing) are answered by "because native speakers are able to choose among multiple valid ways of expressing themselves" Terseness is often considered rude, so that people will not always cut down their utterances to the minimum number of words needed to convey the information required.

Answer (score -1):

It most likely means traffic lights, because you wouldn't specify a street lamp or anything else attached to a building. But the reason behind calling it this is just most likely for artistic distinction.